# File (FRM) not found? Cant view the tables?

Tags: backup, files, mysql

I have 2 version of database backup.

```
Mysqldump > db_backup.sql
```

&

`FRM` files (tables files)

The `db_backup.sql` file is corrupted; it is 0 KB. I think I can't help with it anymore.

Now I only have the `FRM` files. After I copy all the `FRM` files to my database folder, in `phpmyadmin`, I got this message: `File not found 'users' errno2`

`Users` is one of the important tables; I can't lose it. Is there any way to repair the `FRM` files? The files are there. Why does it say "File not found"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.frm` files don't contain the data; the `.ibd` files have the data, if you have `innodb_file_per_table` in the `my.cnf` file. If you don't have `innodb_file_per_table` in the `my.cnf` file, the data is in the `ibdata1` file.

The `.frm` files are the table format files. They have the information about the columns in the table. If all you have are `.frm` files, your data is gone.